# How to inject PCM stream into new virtual microphone?

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, microphone

I load a PCM stream from a server. Now I want to use this PCM stream as a microphone (so the user can select it in TeamSpeak, Skype etc..). I guess it's necessary to write a driver for a new virtual microphone and inject the audio stream. And idea on how to approach this?

The only hint I was able to find is Microsoft's [Virtual Audio Device Driver Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/virtual-audio-device-3d4e6150), particularly the "pcmex". However I still dont know how to inject my stream into this yet silent virtual microphone.

Comment: Hi, Alexander! I'm working on the same issue. If you have any solutions - please share.